# sqlalchemy error: object() takes no parameters error after dropping column from db model.py

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I get the following error `typeerror: object() takes no parameters` on a mysql command which doesn't make sense to me. The error is due to  dropping the username column from my models.py which I no longer require

[image]

Below is the user model definition in my models.py file, I want to drop the username column and get the above error when I remove it from the model

```
class User(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)
   firstname = db.Column(db.String(128))
   lastname = db.Column(db.String(128))
   email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
```

Below is my db_migrate.py file which I used to update the db. I got this from  [Miguel's database tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)

```
#!flask/bin/python
import types
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + ('/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (v+1))
tmp_module = types.ModuleType('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec(old_model, tmp_module.__dict__)
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

This is the 005_migration.py file

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *


from migrate.changeset import schema
pre_meta = MetaData()
post_meta = MetaData()
user = Table('user', pre_meta,
    Column('id', INTEGER(display_width=11), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('username', VARCHAR(length=32)),
    Column('email', VARCHAR(length=120)),
    Column('password_hash', VARCHAR(length=128)),
    Column('firstname', VARCHAR(length=128)),
    Column('lastname', VARCHAR(length=128)),
)


def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Upgrade operations go here. Don't create your own engine; bind
    # migrate_engine to your metadata
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    pre_meta.tables['user'].columns['username'].drop()


def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Operations to reverse the above upgrade go here.
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    pre_meta.tables['user'].columns['username'].create()
```

Comment: I think it is better to let `alembic` module handle for you the db migrations. Did u try that?

Comment: Plus, I think data types for columns is of the form (`Integer`, `String`...)...

Comment: In the future, please don't embed tracebacks as images.

Comment: @IronFist thanks for the recommendation. I understand sqlalchemy-migrate is fairly popular too. I will look into alembic if I can't get this working.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Will do in the future. Thanks for the advice

Comment: sqlalchemy-migrate is a 3rd party tool that hasn't seen a release in a year, where as alembic is developed by the author of SQLAlchemy and has active development.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I wasn't aware of that. I will try out alembic! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong data types for Column definition, here are the right ones:

```
from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String)

user = Table('user', pre_meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('username', String(32)),
    Column('email', String(120)),
    Column('firstname', String(128)),
    Column('lastname', String(128)),
)
```

For more details on SQLAlchemy Column and Data Types, check this [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#module-sqlalchemy.types)

Comment: but the code in 005_migration.py is generated by sqlalchemy-migrate. In my models.py, I defined it as SQLAlchemy.Integer
`id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`

Comment: @GucciProgrammer .. The migration script is still experimental in my understanding, try to manually fix those data types and you should be ready to migrate .. And like I suggested to you...`Alembic` is much better...

Comment: I will try out Alembic. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is not due to removing a column, it originates from the line

```
Column('id', INTEGER(display_width=11), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
```

which the traceback clearly indicates.

[`INTEGER`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER), which you import with `from sqlalchemy import *` takes no arguments, such as *display_width*. You should be using the dialect specific data type [`sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.INTEGER`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.INTEGER).

Comment: but the code in 005_migration.py is generated by sqlalchemy-migrate. In my models.py, I defined it as SQLAlchemy.Integer
`id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`. Also, it migrates fine when I keep the line `username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)`

Comment: Then it is generated incorrectly, probably by directly reading the table definition from your DB, but using the wrong types as can be seen. The tool is broken. I also recommend giving [alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/) a go. What does the generated migration look like, if you "keep the line"? I'd guess it is empty, as there are no changes to migrate.